# 'initializing' : truncation from 'int' to 'char'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
using namespace std;
char x = 'Game';
char y = x;
char z=y;
char z ='Play';
cout << z << endl;
cout << x << endl;
}
```

I am just a beginner of C++ and using Visual C++ 2012. When I compiled the above code, I get an error, `"truncation from 'int' to 'char'`".
Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Comment: How do you want "Game" to be a `char`? Did you mean to use `string`?

Comment: They still give me a error when I use string.

Comment: Because you should surround it with `"` and not `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what you really want to do ...

If you want to declare a string:

```
char * x = "Game";
string xs = "Game"; // C++
```

If you want to declare a char:

```
char y = 'G';
char z = y;
char z2 = x[0];  // remember: in C/C++, arrays begin in 0
```

You can't declare twice the same variable:

```
char z = y;
char z = 'Play';  // 'Play' is not a char and you can't redeclare z
```

So, final code seems like;

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string x = "Game";
    char y = x[0];

    char z = y;
    string z2 = "Play";

    cout << z << endl;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off just using `std::string`

```
std::string x = "Game";
cout << x << endl;
```

You must use `"` instead of single quotes . Single quotes are used to represent a single `char` not an array

Comment: He's `using namespace`. `string x` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

§6.4.4.4.10

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., 'ab'), [...] is implementation-defined.

Chances are it's being treated as a `long` or similar type, which is "truncated" to fit into a `char`.

You need double quotes and to use `std::string`:

```
string x = "Game";
```