# C: Multiple backslashes used in char

Tags: c

I have the following `C` code but I don't understand it

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c = '\\\\';
    printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

I have created a `char` with two characters in it. I get a compiler warning which says truncating from `int` to `char`. How is `\\\\` an `int`? Isn't it a string?

I was looking at the syntax of acceptable character literals when I run into this problem.

These are the escape sequences I have found online:

```
newline
\n
backslash
\\
horizontal tab
\t
question mark
? or \?
vertical tab
\v
single quote
\'
backspace
\b
double quote
\"
carriage return
\r
the null character
\0
form feed
\f
octal
\ooo
alert (bell)
\a
hexadecimal
\xhhh
```

Comment: Strings in C are written in double quotes. And having a different type.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, why is this valid syntax? ill append that to my question

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797979/initializing-truncation-from-int-to-char?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: It's called "Multicharacter literal".

Comment: multichar literals are meant to be \x1111 or \o1111 ? there is no prefix for \\?

Comment: Here are the semantics: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4

Comment: Note that you'll get the same behavior with `char c = 'ab';`. Using backslash characters adds an extra level of confusion, until you realize that two backslashes are seen by the compiler as a single backslash.

Comment: @Har No, a multi-byte character literal is a character literal that, after parsing, results in multiple bytes within a character literal. For example, `'\\\\'` is parsed as if you had typed `'\x5C\x5C'`, assuming an ASCII-based source character set.

Comment: It worth noting, that the result is implementation defined, as it depends on both - encoding and endianess.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In C, `'\\\\'` is a _character-constant_ of type `int` using a sequence of multibyte characters.  C does not call  it a _literal_.  C does have _string literals_ and _compound literals_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, all non-wide *character constants*  are type `int`.  Examples below.

```
'a', '\\', '\x0012', '\n', '\\\\', '\0', 'ab'

printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x %x\n", 'a', '\\', '\x0012', '\n', '\\\\', '\0', 'ab');
// Output - this may differ - but used for illustration
61 5c 12 a 5c5c 0 6162
```

The message "warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]" or the like alerts the coder to the idea that the value of the `int` constant `'\\\\'` is out of range of a `char` and deserves review.

```
// Both may give a warning that the constant is out-or-range for a `char`.
char c = '\\\\';
char d = 1000;
```